# Excel VBA - impossible to launch the code

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code, I could launch it to debugg but I don't know what I did I cannot anymore.
When I click on "Launch Sub/UserForm", nothing happens. It was working before.

Do you have any idea of what's wrong ?

**EDIT:** I noticed also that F8 is not reviewing all the lines. It springs directly from line 13 to line 25.

```
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
    
    Sub Listprice()
    
    Number_lift = 3
    Col_HK = 3
    Col_koko = 4
    
    Do While Number_lift < 9
    Level = 6
    TH = 20
    Line_x = 6
    Do While Level < 5
    Range("P14").Value = TH
    Range("P16").Value = Level
    Workbooks("Kalk.xlsm").Worksheets("Kalkulation").Range("C26").Copy
    Workbooks("List_EN_V1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sht1").Cells(Col_HK, Line_x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Workbooks("Kalk.xlsm").Worksheets("Kalkulation").Range("C20").Copy
    Workbooks("List_EN_V1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sht1").Cells(Col_HK, Line_x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    TH = TH + 3
    Level = Level + 1
    Line_x = Line_x + 1
    Sleep (5000)
    Loop
    Number_lift = Number_lift + 5
    Col_HK = Col_HK + 4
    Col_koko = Col_koko + 4
    Loop


    End Sub
```

Thank you !

Comment: Where this "Launch Sub/UserForm" is? Do you mean `Listprice` sub, or forgot pasting the appropriate code?

Comment: I mean the button in Excel code editor "Visual Basic" to launch the code. Yes, I want to launch sub Listprice().

Comment: You set ```Level = 6``` and then check it in ```Do While Level < 5``` this condition is always false